# Spring boot not executing schema.sql in integration tests

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, liquibase

I have defined liquibase migrations that don't pass because I have to release schema.sql first, which is to be enforced as part of integration tests.
Unfortunately as embedded postgres starts (https://github.com/zonkyio/embedded-postgres) liquibase migrations start immediately after that and schema.sql is ignored.
schema.sql is located in test/resources/schema.sql.
I'm looking for a way to run several SQL queries (create database, create role) that will be run each time embedded postgres is run in tests.

I tried with both schema.sql and data.sql. I'd like to avoid importing additional libraries that would just enforce this (like Pre-Liquibase).

Comment: Hello, it would be hard to implement. Maybe you can just add the SQL queries at the very beginning of you Liquibase migration scripts. To be executed only in test environment. Just an idea.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work because one of the queries I want to do is CREATE DATABASE, which cannot be done in a transaction, and every migration is a transaction.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add the SQL commands at the very beginning of you Liquibase migration scripts. To be executed only in test environment.

As you stated in the comment the Postgres CREATE DATABASE command can't run in a transaction. There is an attribute `runInTransaction` in the Liquibase changeset configuration to run a changeset without transaction:

```
<changeSet  id="1"  author="enccne"  runInTransaction="false">
    <sql>CREATE DATABASE myDatabase;</sql>
</changeSet>
```

More details here: https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/run-in-transaction.html

Answer (score 0):

Running your sql script after a database installation (or Docker deployment) is something you can do with many (automated or not) tools.

- Check Ansible to run your SQL scripts.
- Check querying tools like Datagrip, PgSQL, and others PostgreSQL database clients.

Comment: What's an example of use? The script would be launched automatically when integration tests are run in the spring application. Execution in the following order:
1. Zonkyio embedded postgres
2. Script sql
3. Liquibase migrations
4. Test methods.
The application uses the mentioned dependencies (liquibase, zonkyio embedded postgres, spring-boot-starter-data-jpa)

Comment: I don't know how a database client would help solve this problem. It's about executions, for example, schema.sql after the database has been created in the context of spring tests

Comment: With Ansible, you can automate the database creation part and running SQL scripts.
If you want to stay with java spring and your dependencies, @Mar-Z has posted another answer to create a database. Add a db user with limited privileges to run your test suites with your test profile, and run.

Comment: And I can listen you don't want to add other dep, but Pre-Liquibase is done to handle your problem very well. Using test scope in your maven pom.xml is not hurting your deployment at all.